# Mysql select from multiple tables and get zero count

Tags: mysql

I have a simple db with 2 tables --

questions & answers

both have a questionid field and I'm trying to get a list of all of the questions with a count of all of the answers - the problem is that there are some questions that don't have answers.

```
SELECT questions.*,COUNT(answers.questionid) AS num_answers 
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN answers 
ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid
```

The sql above gives a count of all of the questions that have answers but if there are zero answers then it doesn't appear in the list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_answers
FROM questions LEFT JOIN
     answers
     ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid
```

When you use `count(<column>)` name, you are counting the number of non-NULL values in the column.  By using a column in the second table, you are only counting matches.

In addition, you do not need `questions.*`.  Most SQL engines would return an error for this.  The query returns only one row anyway, because it is an aggregation query with no `group by`.

EDIT:

If you want this per *question*, then use `group by` and count the matches using the column in `answers`:

```
SELECT questions.*, 
       COUNT(answers.questionid) as num_answers
FROM questions LEFT JOIN
     answers
     ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid
GROUP BY questions.questionid
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Just checked that and it only returns num_results = x.   I should've been clearer.   I need the question title and details and then the count of how many answers there are (hence me doing questions.*)

Comment: Thanks +1 - my question wasn't clear enough but the group by was the missing link - thanks for clarification.

Comment: If you use `group by`, then you probably want to count the column.

Answer (score 1):

Also group by the columns you want to select

```
SELECT questions.id, questions.title, COUNT(answers.questionid) AS num_answers 
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid
GROUP BY questions.id, questions.title
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the trick.    My mistake was the group by - still learning!